# Shadow darkness in ThreeJS and object opacity

Tags: three.js

I have an object that fades its material to an opacity of 50%, but I noticed the shadow does not change with its opacity.

If the opacity of an object is 50% alpha'd . What I would like to see is that objects shadow be 50% of its shadow at a 100%.

What's a good way to handle this using threejs?

Edit: my specific scenerio has multiple meshes at varying opacities casting shadows on multiple meshes.

Comment: What do you mean?  Is the shadow 100% dark but you don't want it to be?

Comment: If the opacity of an object is 50% I would like its shadow to be 50% of its shadow at a 100%.

Answer (score 4):

There is a **`shadowMaterial`** that is invisible but only renders shadow. You can set its `opacity` to mimic shadow darkness, here is a demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/f17Lz5ux/5336/

```
var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
planeMaterial.opacity = 0.5;
var shadowPlane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, planeMaterial );
shadowPlane.receiveShadow = true;
```

**Drawback**: In older releases there has been a `shadowDarkness`-property that has been removed. Now you need extra geometry and material to emulate what has been a simple property.

Comment: Good answer, was helpful. Also consider that `shadowDarkness` didn't allow to change opacity, only darkness (hence the name). `shadowMaterial` is much more flexible: you can change shadows opacity and color to create many complex effects.

Comment: downside is when you start having multiple meshes with shadows and multiple meshes receiving shadows things start getting way more complex to manage , and not practical unless you have a simple scene.

Comment: to be clear on what i mean : http://jsfiddle.net/5vyj23gL/ . I want the shadow of the box on the right to not have opacity